# no outbound connections

Tags: server

I have been running 14.04 server without a problem.  This morning I was told by my son that the server wasn't working.  I have minecraft on it and it has been working flawlessly.
Minecraft returned 'authentication server not found'

Further checking determined that I was unable to obtain an outbound connection.  I can't ssh or ping anything outside of the network like sonic.net.  I got messages like unable to resolve host.  I can log onto the server via my network so at least incoming connections are good.  I can connect through a port forward connection from the outside as well. I can ssh from another computer, so that verifies home network integrity.

here is my /etc/network/interfaces config file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
# auto eth0
auto eth4
# iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth4 inet static
address 192.168.1.170
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1

# This is an autoconfigured IPv6 interface
# iface eth0 inet6 auto
iface eth4 inet6 auto
```

any ideas how to test/troubleshoot or repair this weird problem?

Comment: Whats the output of `ping -c2 8.8.8.8 &>/dev/null && echo "OK" || echo "NOT OK"` ?

Comment: Whats the output of ping -c2 8.8.8.8 &>/dev/null && echo "OK" || echo "NOT OK" ? –  heemayl-     Echo returns "ok"  Thanks!

Comment: Thats means you have a DNS issue. Do you use the DNS given from the ISP?

Comment: Whats the output of `grep "nameserver" /etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: ok, I had just gotten to that conclusion ;-) Still need help.  That file is there, although I should add the following: It is just a server.  No dns, email or other.  this used to work perfectly.  apache says can't find dns name so using 127.0.0.0 or maybe 0.0.1?  can I just add primary and secondary dns entries?  it used to get them from the router.  At least I thought...

Comment: Are other connections that use the router working properly?

Comment: Yes, all other computers on network can access dns with out problem(s)

Comment: Whats the output of `grep "nameserver" /etc/resolv.conf` ?

Comment: Nothing!  I looked in it as well, and there is nothing in there besides a do no not edit statement.  Should we take this to e-mail?

Comment: we are almost there..do you know your ISP's DNS?

Comment: yes, Comcast Domain Name System (DNS) servers: Primary IPv4: 75.75.75.75. Secondary IPv4: 75.75.76.76. Primary IPv6: 2001:558:FEED::1.Feb 13, 2015 - it is listed in my router and they work.

Comment: Run the command `sudo sed -i.bak '/gateway/a dns-nameservers 75.75.75.75 75.75.76.76' /etc/network/interfaces` and then run `sudo ifdown eth4 && sudo ifup eth4` ..now try everything..

Comment: heemayl!  You are SO wonderful!  It works great!  THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!  WOW  WOW  WOW

Comment: Happy to help :) ..let me put this as an answer..please accept that as the answer to your question so that others can be notified that the issue is resolved..

Comment: No problem :) ..please check the answer..more info are given..

Answer (score 0):

You are having a DNS issue due to the fact that the DNS is not configured, you need to add the right name server entry(ies) in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Run the following command to add the name server addresses provided by your ISP to the `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
sudo sed -i.bak '/gateway/a dns-nameservers 75.75.75.75 75.75.76.76' /etc/network/interfaces
```

Here the `sed` command will add the line `dns-nameservers 75.75.75.75 75.75.76.76` after the `gateway 192.168.1.1` line. The `75.75.75.75` and `75.75.76.76` IPs are the ISP provided DNS addresses. (Also note that the original file is backed up as `/etc/network/interfaces.bak`). Now you are all set as far as the DNS is concerned.

Now run the following to make the interface (`eth4`) down and up so that our modifications are applied immediately:

```
sudo ifdown eth4 && sudo ifup eth4
```